# Output of the query is not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the below query in order to split the value of a column in to two columns and is working fine but it is not working the way I expected. Below is the query along with the output which I'm getting.

### Query:

```
 select distinct
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(Asset, '(.+):.+@',1,1,'i',1) as InstanceName,
 upper(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Asset, '.+@(.+)s-',1,1,'i',1)) as ServerName,
 Asset  FROM table
```

### Output which I'm getting:

```
Servername  Instancename    Asset
HKP02LP1802 ACMHKPU1        ACMHKPU1:ACRMUTF@hkp02lp1802s-rs6000.hk.hsbc
NULL        NULL            DB2IMFI:GWISMFI@hkpb2ls0012s.hk.hsbc
NULL        NULL            DB2ICNC:CNCUSER@hkpa2ls0065s.hk.hsbc
NULL        NULL            DB2INST1:RAEC@pdb1-ctis-hase.hk.hsbc    
NULL        NULL            DB2IVIS:GWSVIS_@hkpb2ls0011s.hk.hsbc
NULL        NULL            CNW20011136\PCNISDS01@cnw20011136.hbap.adroot.hsbc
NULL        NULL            BDW00142954\PBDRMSS01@bdw00142954.hbap.adroot.hsbc
NULL        NULL            AUNSW0320015@aunsw0320015.au.hsbc
NULL        NULL            HKW00100479C02\IMPACT360@hkw00100479c02.hbap.adroot.hsbc
NULL        NULL            HKW00100430\PHKLRRS02@hkw00100430.hbap.adroot.hsbc
NULL        NULL            JPW00142975@jpw00142975.jp.hsbc
NULL        NULL            MY000LAG0005@my000lag0005.my.hsbc
NULL        NULL            BPMHKPO62@hkpa8ls0082o.hk.hsbc
NULL        NULL            PHKCECA11@hkpa8ls0132-vip.hk.hsbc
NULL        NULL            PHKDCYA1@hkp3pl0308v2-dcya1-opt-prod.hk.hsbc
NULL        NULL            PHKCTMA7@hkp3pl0408v3-ctma7-opt.hk.hsbc
```

### Output which I would like to see:

```
Servername      Instancename                        Asset
HKP02LP1802     ACMHKPU1                           ACMHKPU1:ACRMUTF@hkp02lp1802s-rs6000.hk.hsbc
hkpb2ls0012     DB2IMF                             DB2IMFI:GWISMFI@hkpb2ls0012s.hk.hsbc
hkpa2ls0065     DB2ICNC                            DB2ICNC:CNCUSER@hkpa2ls0065s.hk.hsbc    
pdb1-ctis-hase  DB2INST1                           DB2INST1:RAEC@pdb1-ctis-hase.hk.hsbc    
hkpb21s0011     DB2IVIS                            DB2IVIS:GWSVIS_@hkpb2ls0011s.hk.hsbc
cmw20011136     CNW20011136                        CNW20011136\PCNISDS01@cnw20011136.hbap.adroot.hsbc
db200142954     BDW00142954                        BDW00142954\PBDRMSS01@bdw00142954.hbap.adroot.hsbc
aunsw0320015    AUNSW0320015                       AUNSW0320015@aunsw0320015.au.hsbc
hkw00100479c02  HKW00100479C02                     HKW00100479C02\IMPACT360@hkw00100479c02.hbap.adroot.hsbc
hkw00100430     HKW00100430                        HKW00100430\PHKLRRS02@hkw00100430.hbap.adroot.hsbc
jpw00142975     JPW00142975                        JPW00142975@jpw00142975.jp.hsbc
my000lag0005    MY000LAG0005                       MY000LAG0005@my000lag0005.my.hsbc
hkpa8ls00082o   BPMHKPO62                          BPMHKPO62@hkpa8ls0082o.hk.hsbc
hkpa8ls0132     PHKCECA11                          PHKCECA11@hkpa8ls0132-vip.hk.hsbc
hkp3pl0308v2    PHKDCYA1                           PHKDCYA1@hkp3pl0308v2-dcya1-opt-prod.hk.hsbc
hkp3pl0408v3    PHKCTMA7                           PHKCTMA7@hkp3pl0408v3-ctma7-opt.hk.hsbc
```

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: I can't duplicate your results. When I run `select REGEXP_SUBSTR('DB2IMFI:GWISMFI@hkpb2ls0012s.hk.hsbc', '(.+):.+@',1,1,'i',1) from dual;`, it returns the instance name you're looking for, not NULL. Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere in your query?

Comment: Why in this case: `@hkp02lp1802s-rs6000` you want `hkp02lp1802s` as an output - without minus sign, while in this case: `@pdb1-ctis-hase` you want 
 `pdb1-ctis-hase` including minus signs ?

Comment: it's working fine for the instance name for the above asset which you are referring to but for some assets which are like 'HKW00145086\PMCDGSQL01@hkw00145086.hk.hsbc' and 'HKW00141042@hkw00141042.hk.hsbc' it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your expected output is ambiguous as described in comments. This should probably work fine for all except `pdb1-ctis-hase`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    regexp_substr(asset,'([^:\\@]+)[:\\@]',1,1,'i',1) AS instancename,
    upper(regexp_replace(regexp_substr(asset,'@([^\.-]+)[\.-]',1,1,'i',1),'[so]$','') ) AS servername,
    asset
FROM
    yourtable;
```

Comment: that's perfect and don't worry about the 'pdb1-ctis-hase', I will check that. Thanks again for your help.